# Monte Carlo method for confidence intervals

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, python, confidence-interval, monte-carlo

I would like to attempt a Monte Carlo procedure to filter composite anomalies at 90% confidence level from the rest of the composite anomalies. My data is a NetCDF of hourly surface temperature that I've aggregated to daily to get their composite daily anomalies. I'm doing the same methodology on different variables (humidity, pressure etc) too. I'm not sure how to go about doing the Monte Carlo simulation to test for the significance of the anomalies. Any recommendation/advice is appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to be more specific. "Monte Carlo" is just a fancy way of saying "simulation", and simulation may range everywhere from tossing a coin to using a supercomputer to simulate Earth's climate, and will be problem-specific.

Comment: Frankly, I don't mind the method of testing, but I particularly want to test for the significance of the trend of the outliers in the data. I'm interested in outliers that are significant at a particular confidence level. Perhaps a student's t-test suffice?

Comment: You need to tell us more about your data and the statistical model you have in mind. Please, edit for more details.